# Banach algebra of $C^{1}([0,1])$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, banach-algebras

I want to show that $\mathscr{A}=\{f \in C^{1}([0,1]) \}$ with norm 
$$\Vert f \Vert_{C^{1}} = \Vert f \Vert+ \Vert f^{'} \Vert,$$
is $\textbf{semi-simple}$.

I see a method as following:

To show that $r(f):= \sup\{ \vert \lambda \vert :  \lambda e-f \notin G(\mathscr{A})\}
=0 $, 
where $G(\mathscr{A})$ is the invertible elements of $\mathscr{A}$.

And $ r(f)=0 $ means $\mathscr{A}$ semi-simple.

But I do not understand the reason. Please help me to explain why does it work?

Comment: What is $r(f)$?

Comment: @Aweygan $r(f)$ is the radius of the spectrum $\sigma(f)$.

Comment: Something's not right.  If $f$ is the constant $1$ function, then $\sigma(f)=\{1\}$, so $r(f)=1\neq0$.

Comment: @Aweygan If it is wrong, how to show $\mathscr{A}$ is semi-simple in the other way?

Comment: I posted an answer with my thoughts.  Please let me know if this is what you meant.

Comment: @Aweygan Yes, you are right! Thanks!!!

Comment: You're welcome.  Glad to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that instead of $r(f)$ you meant to put something along the lines of $\text{Rad}(\mathscr A)$, which denotes the intersection of all maximal ideals of $\mathscr A$.  For if $\text{Rad}(\mathscr A)=\{0\}$, then by definition $\mathscr A$ is semi-simple.

To show $\text{Rad}(\mathscr A)=\{0\}$, just note for each $x\in[0,1]$, the evaluation $f\mapsto f(x)$ is a complex homomorphism of $\mathscr A$, whose kernel is a maximal ideal of $\mathscr A$.  Thus if $f\in\text{Rad}(\mathscr A)$, $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in[0,1]$, so that $f=0$.